# Julia: Building multiple types in parallel

Tags: julia

I am trying to use parallelism in Julia to construct several large types (specifically, gaussian mixture models via sklearn through PyCall).

If I were doing this in series, I would do:

```
models = Array(GMM, N)
for i = 1 : N
    params = ...
    models[i] = train_gmm(params)
end
```

However, I should be able to do this is parallel. I am having trouble figuring out where to start, since SharedArrays and @parallel don't seem to be the right thing for me.

I was trying to use @spawn, but found the following:

```
function f1()
    rand(10000000)
    rand(10000000)
    rand(10000000)
    rand(10000000)
    rand(10000000)
end

function f2()
    a = @spawn rand(10000000)
    b = @spawn rand(10000000)
    c = @spawn rand(10000000)
    d = @spawn rand(10000000)
    e = @spawn rand(10000000)
    a_r = fetch(a)
    b_r = fetch(b)
    c_r = fetch(c)
    d_r = fetch(d)
    e_r = fetch(e)
end

f1()
f2()
println(@elapsed(f1()))
println(@elapsed(f2()))
```

f1 takes 0.21 seconds, f2 takes 0.32 seconds! Is there something about @spawn that I am missing?

**EDIT**

It looks like doing:

```
function f1()
    [sum(rand(100000000)),
    sum(rand(100000000)),
    sum(rand(100000000)),
    sum(rand(100000000)),
    sum(rand(100000000))]
end

function f2()
    a = @spawn sum(rand(100000000))
    b = @spawn sum(rand(100000000))
    c = @spawn sum(rand(100000000))
    d = @spawn sum(rand(100000000))
    e = @spawn sum(rand(100000000))
    [fetch(a), fetch(b), fetch(c), fetch(d), fetch(e)]
end
```

Causes f2() to run faster than f1() and it is more in-line with what I want. I'll go with this unless someone has a better, official way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your edit has got it correct.

```
IAINMAC:~ idunning$ julia -p 3

julia> @everywhere function foo()
         sleep(2)
       end

julia> @time [foo(), foo(), foo()]
elapsed time: 6.017959282 seconds (294088 bytes allocated)
3-element Array{Nothing,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing

julia> function bar()
         a = @spawn foo()
         b = @spawn foo()
         c = @spawn foo()
         [fetch(a), fetch(b), fetch(c)]
       end
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time bar()
elapsed time: 2.030760103 seconds (199720 bytes allocated)
3-element Array{Nothing,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
```

or even more elegantly with `pmap`:

```
julia> @everywhere function foo(a::Int)
         sleep(a)
       end

julia> @time pmap(foo,1:3)
elapsed time: 3.004821524 seconds (448540 bytes allocated)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing

julia> @time map(foo,1:3)
elapsed time: 6.006557822 seconds (1368 bytes allocated)
3-element Array{Nothing,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
```

Comment: Thank you! Does putting the `fetch` calls in an array force them all to be executed simultaneously?

Comment: `fetch` is blocking, so I imagine they block in order, but I'm not sure (and it wouldn't matter I guess). Thats why using pmap is better, because it will fire off the first N tasks, and as soon as any returns it will start a new one.